# How to make JComponent click-through?

Tags: java, swing, awt, transparency, click-through

I found lots of question like this but don't find the answer of exactly this question. I want to make a transparent rectangle for example and it will be just for design not for functionality. So I want when I click on its border and I have a button in another window under the border of my rectangle - the button to be clicked. Is it possible? This is my code but it does not work as intended.

```
public class ClickThroughWindow {

    public static final int RECT_SIZE = 80;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestPanel panel = new TestPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(RECT_SIZE, RECT_SIZE));
        panel.setOpaque(false);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Crossfire");
        // Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        // frame.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - frame.getSize().width / 2 -
        // RECT_SIZE
        // / 2, dim.height / 2 - frame.getSize().height / 2 - RECT_SIZE
        // / 2);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2446519137290816513L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(getBackground());
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(40));
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

here is an example:  postimg.org/image/t4gzczzc3. 
When click where the arrow points I want to go to first tab of my browser. (even my program is on top)

Comment: *"I want to make a transparent rectangle for example and it will be just for design not for functionality."* What does 'design' mean?  Is it a spacer element?

Comment: If your `TestPane` doesn't have `MosueListener` attached to, then the mouse events should pass through it

Comment: how to make this with the mouse listener ?

Comment: I want when I go through the border with the mouse to be like there is no border !

Comment: How are these elements overlapped?

Comment: the border is on top of the button of another window for example. I want when click on the border the button of the other window to be clicked. Just like the border do not exist !

Comment: By window, do you mean another physical window or some kind of component?

Comment: Maybe like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513)?

Comment: its like this: http://postimg.org/image/t4gzczzc3/ . When click where the arrow points I want to go to first tab of my browser. (even my program is on top)